# Validation or if statements

Tags: php, laravel

I’m implementing **follow** feature and I want to make sure that

1. A user should not follow the same user twice
2. Users should not follow themselves

Should I put the aforementioned conditions insife the **follow** method ?

```
class User extends model
{
     public function follow($user)
     {
           if($this->is($user) || $this->isFollowing($user))
           {
                return;
           }
     }
}
```

Or should I **validate** the given user ?

```
class FollowController
{
      public function store()
      {
         request()->validate([
            'username' => ['exists:users,name', new NotYourself, new AlreadyFollowing]
         ]);
      }
}
```

Or is there a better way ?

Comment: Answers to that question will be opinion based, which wouldn't be that helpful. I'd prefer option 2 as it seems to be the cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

B001 is technically correct, but my opinion is that it's not a matter of opinion. Best-practices would dictate going with the second option. Model classes are better suited for context-agnostic handling of tables, not business-logic. And if you apply your rules in the form of input validation, that gives you access to a few other bells and whistles if the validation fails. Specifically, an error response capable of informing the browser what input field to highlight to tell the user they did something wrong. Taken a step further, I'd suggest placing those rules inside a [custom FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) object instead of the Controller method.

Locking down the endpoint like this is good practice regardless, to prevent low-level hacks with Postman or some-such. But taking a step further back from that, I'd recommend not offering the UI option in the first place. Check out [Gates and Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization). You can write compartmentalized access rules, typically intended for authorization, and use them to dictate whether the "follow" button is available at all.

Comment: I also like better the second option because I can let the user know what went wrong, using the validation error messages. I am already hiding the button in the UI, but I believe is a good idea to also handle these cases in the backend